# Vue JS How to correct "Avoid mutating a prop directly"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a main comonent view with a button :

```
    <mdb-btn
                      color="light-blue"
                      outline="white"
                      rounded
                      @click="showLoginRegister = true"
                      icon="users"
                      iconRight
                  >Inscription / Connexion</mdb-btn>

  export default {
  name: "Landing",
  components: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showLoginRegister: false
    };
  }
};
```

and in this parent view a sub component (a modal window) :

```
<modal-inscription :showLoginRegister="showLoginRegister"></modal-inscription>
```

And in the modal-inscription component :

```
<mdb-modal :show="showLoginRegister" @close="showLoginRegister = false">...
```

I add a prop attribute :

```
props: ['showLoginRegister'],
```

And it works when I click on the button the modal window appears but I have this error message in the js console : "[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "showLoginRegister"

I understand the message but how can I avoid it by using a local variable in the child component ?

Or perhaps I don't use the rignt method...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your structure but you can get the same structure as below and it should work the same way, just send a `false` value to your parent.
Just send the data back to the parent (`$emit` from the child) and update the given prop in the parent ! More info on this pattern in the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

[`computed setters`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) may also help but it's a bit more complex to understand so rather stick with a basic use-case. Same goes for the `v-model` [syntax on components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

---

You need to have a props/emit (aka parent/child) relationship between your components like

**Parent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <child :name="name" @update-name="updateName"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'bob',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateName(newName) {
      this.name = newName
    },
  },
  components: {
    Child: () => import('./components/child'),
  },
}
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
    <button @click="changeName">append nice</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['name'],
  methods: {
    changeName() {
      this.$emit('update-name', this.name + ' nice')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Also Michael Thiessen did a blog post on this: https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case the button is in the parent view not in the child view.

Comment: I don't get your structure. If you could explain it a bit better or make a reproducible link, will be able to help but here, I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

As warning message said - if you change prop, it doesn't affect parent data and after parent component will re-render, your prop will be overwritten.
To avoid this you should $emit event from child component and mutate prop in parent component.

```
<mdb-modal :show="showLoginRegister" @close="$emit('close-login')">

    <mdb-btn
                      color="light-blue"
                      outline="white"
                      rounded
                      @click="showLoginRegister = true"
                      icon="users"
                      iconRight
                      @close-login="showLoginRegister = false"
                  >Inscription / Connexion</mdb-btn>

  export default {
  name: "Landing",
  components: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showLoginRegister: false
    };
  }
};
```

Also you can use Vuex, Event Bus or $root/$parent to communicate between components directly.

Comment: Vuex will not prevent data mutation (still need to pass a copy of the object with `cloneDeep`) and eventBus is not a thing to use, nor are `$root/$parent` (really deprecated in an usual workflow). Here, it's a direct n+1 structure, so totally overkill and not recommended.

Comment: In your answer I don't see the difference with my code, showLoginRegister is still used. How the child component knows the parent click ?